# Problem when trying to add an element to a page using appendChild in JS. Throws an error: "is null, undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to authorize the site through Firebase, everything works as it should, the data is sent to the Firebase server.
But further, in the **signIn** function, I try to create a **h2-element** and put the mail data into it, which the user entered and clicked on the Login button (I want the mail to be displayed on the site instead of the name), then an error appears on the line where I highlighted with a red arrow: "**autorizationName is null, undefined** ", no data is sent to html. I can’t understand why, so help, please, I’m recently studying JS to figure it out.

This can happen if I added one **JS** script to two **HTML** pages?
That is, index.html and autorization.html to the two I added autorization.js
I wanted it to be redirected to the main page when authorizing from one page.

```
  const login = document.querySelector(".form-login")
  login.addEventListener('click', signIn)

function signIn() {
  const email = document.querySelector(".email").value
  const password = document.querySelector(".password").value
//   e.preventDefault()

  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in 
          const user = userCredential.user;                        
          console.log("Email firebase: ",  user.email);           

          const user2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.email))

          const autorizationName = document.querySelector(".autorization-name__container");
          const autorizationNameTitle = document.createElement("h2");
          autorizationNameTitle.textContent = user2;
          autorizationNameTitle.classList.add("autorization-name__title");
          

          autorizationName.appendChild(autorizationNameTitle); // Error: autorizationName is null, undefined
          window.location.replace("http://192.168.1.65:5500/")  
                 
      })

      .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          alert(errorMessage + ", " + errorCode);
      });
  }
```

Here are screenshots:

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Please do not share screenshots of your code: paste it in your question instead and format it as code.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about it, the first question is here

Answer (score 0):

At the line of

```
autorizationName.appendChild(autorizationNameTitle);
```

you are getting an error which says that `authorizationName` is null, undefined. So, logically, we need to take a look at the place where its value was modified the last time (in this case, it is its initialization):

```
const autorizationName = document.querySelector(".autorization-name__container");
```

And it is a known fact that if your call to `document.querySelector` yields `undefined`, then the selector did not match any elements. So, the reason for the error is that there is no element in your page with the `class` of `authorization-name__container` at the time you try to find it. So, you will need to fix the selector or find out when the given element is created.

Answer (score -1):

It is 100% an error with the string '.authorization-name__container', try to copy paste this class from where you have it in your code and double check for mispelled words. Then if that doesn't work try to use an id instead of a class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).